# Page refresh leaves first navigation headline in the dropdown menu with a black border - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation

I have the issue that when refreshing a SharePoint site, it leaves black borders around the first navigation headline from every navigation button. It disappears again after the next action.
Can someone explain what that is and how to get rid of it?

Thanks a bunch,
Sarah

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not a common issue per my test. However, we can work together to narrow down and resolve the situation.

1.You could try to clear browser cache then restart it.

2.Try to use a different browser or your browser's InPrivate mode to see if the same error occurs.

3.Check if the same issue occurs with other SharePoint site collections.